Avoid reopening a window on the same object
There is a list of employees. On command, I want to open the employee’s detailed information window. How to avoid repeatedly opening a window for the same employee?
Add a dictionary of opened "employees" to the VM? I can control who opened and closed. Then how can I make sure that when I try to open an “open” employee, the focus is transferred to this window and it pops up?
public class EmployeeListViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

    private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
    {
        get => employees;
        set => SetProperty(ref employees, value);
    }

    private Employee selectedEmployee;
    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get => selectedEmployee;
        set => SetProperty(ref selectedEmployee, value);
    }
    
    public DelegateCommand OpenSelectedEmployeeCardCommand { get; }

    public DocumentsListViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _dialogService = dialogService;

        OpenSelectedEmployeeCardCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenSelectedEmployeeCardCommandExecute);
    }
    
    private void OpenSelectedEmployeeCardCommandExecute()
    {
        _dialogService.Show(
            nameof(EmployeeCard),
            new DialogParameters { { "EmployeeId", SelectedEmployee.Id } },
            result => { });
    }
}


You should create a registry of open employees as service, probably a wrapper around a dictionary with the employee's id as key and the window as value.
When opening an employee, add to the dictionary, if he's not open already. If he's in the dictionary, move his window to the foreground (if that fails, because the window was closed without you noticing somehow, open a new one).
When closing an employee window (attach to the window's events when opening it), remove it from the dictionary.
Side note - everything happens on the ui thread, so you don't have to use a ConcurrentDictionary.
Another side note - be sure to handle everything inside your registry, so that you don't have to pass windows around in the view model world, i.e. the registry could be as simple as
interface IEmployeeWindowRegistry
{
    void ShowEmployee( EmployeeID employeeID );
}

